# adding 'ondblclick' event to dynamic textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, html, double-click

i am creating dynamic textareas via javascript and can set attributes such as class etc but I want to add a 'OnDblClick' attribute to dynamically created textarea and I cant seem to make the mark up work.

any help greatly appreciated

heres the code

```
function creatediv1(id)
{    
    var newtextarea = document.createElement('textarea');  
    newtextarea.setAttribute('class', 'moveable-element');
    newtextarea.setAttribute('onDblClick', 'editor1()'); 
    newtextarea.innerHTML="I can be moved!";
 }
```

Comment: your code is working fine i have run your code in firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ondblclick` is a property, not an attribute, you can set it using:

```
newtextarea.onDblClick = editor1;
```

Comment: Well, i learned it sometime back from SO like you learned it today from SO.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newtextarea.addEventListener('dblclick', editor1, false);
```

Comment: What advantage your method has over `newtextarea.onDblClick = editor1` (which is shorter)?